# Pretraining error increases in each epoch in Deep Belief Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, training-data, rbm, dbn

I am using this implementation of DBN.
http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/code/DBN.py
I am using ecg data to train the model which contains 100 float values (in milivolt unit) per row.
When I run this implementation the pretraining cost goes on increasing I dont understand why.
I am attaching sample input data files and the code of the DBN where I have modified number of input and output units and batchsize. I have modified the 'load_data' code in logistic_sgd.py so I am attaching that file too.
Here is the scenario:

[image]

[image]

Why this is happening? Where I am going wrong?

Link to code and data files:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B02Uz-muAJWWVktyaDFOekU5Ulk

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this RBM/DBN implementation only works on binary inputs. If your input is not binary, you need some extension, e.g. Gaussian-Bernoulli RBM.

Comment: Can you give me a link which has python implementation of Gaussian Bernouli RBM?